# Limit max thread use for multithreaded java app

Tags: linux, java, multithreading

I have downloaded a .jar file and am using `java` with it, and it seems multithreaded, which is great ... unless I don't want it to be multithreaded, or unless I want to use only N threads with it.

Is there a way, in java, to specify how many threads you want to run a .jar file with *without* having access to the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the .jar file I downloaded was single threaded, but Java was using multithreaded garbage collection. To change the number of threads that Java uses for GC, I use `java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2` which fixed the problem.